# What does this Rewrite rule mean?

Tags: http, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

Im installing phpancake, 
there is a folder there shema like this

```
application/
install/
library/
public/
sql_schema/
install.html
install.php
```

What does this rule mean?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /vote/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rewrite has two parts. The first one specifies that if the requested filename is a regular file with a size greater than 0 (`-s`), a symbolic link (`-l`) or a directory (`-d`), rewrite to nowhere, eg. take no action. `[NC,L]` means that the rule is non case sensitive and the last rule that these conditions match.

All other requests are forwarded to `/vote/public/index.php`.

The purpose of this rewrite is that an actual, existing file can be fetched from the server without interference. Without the first rule, every file request (css and js files, images etc) would go to `index.php` which would mess things up pretty badly.

Usually this is written in one declaration, though. You can negate the conditions, and then the `[OR]` statemens can be taken out also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /vote/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

This is equivalent to the original statement.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: can you please explain what would `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` mean? is it just the "size" that options `-s` and `-f` differ in? And also what would be regular files(not Binary?)?

Answer (score 0):

Those are mainly standard rewrites which check if the requested file (or directory or symbolic link) exists on disk, in which case the file/directory/etc. should be used.

All other matches should go to /votes/public/index.php

Comment: from @Tatu Ulmanen's answer can you please explain what would `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` mean? is it just the "size" that options `-s` and `-f` differ in? And also what would be regular files(not Binary?)?

Answer (score 0):

The first rule will pass through all requests that can be mapped to a regular file with a size greater than zero (`-s`), a symbolic link (`-l`) or a directory (`-d`). Every other request is fetched by the second rule and rewritten to */vote/public/index.php*.